# Maximum Likelihood of "Mean Parameters"

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, exponential-family

I'm dealing exclusively with the exponential family of distributions.

The **mean parameters** of the distribution are defined as the expected value of the sufficient statistics in terms of the parameters i.e. $E \left[ T(x) \right]_{p(x|θ)}$.

**Question:** Find the maximum-likelihood value of the mean parameters (as defined above) of the general exponential family distribution $p(x|\theta) = g(\theta) f(x) e^{\theta^T T(x)}$ for a set of iid observations $\{ x^1, x^2, \dots, x^N\}$.

**My problem:** I don't really understand what I am being asked to do! The question says the maximum likelihood of the mean parameters which makes me think I need to solve $\frac{\partial}{\partial E \left[ T(x) \right]} p(x^1,\dots,x^N|\theta) = 0$ which I have no idea how to do.

**However**, if the question means I am supposed to solve $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x^1,\dots,x^N|\theta)=0$ then I know exactly what to do.

Basically, can someone clarify which of these two things it is and how I can tell them apart from the wording in the future?

Comment: Consider beginning by finding the mean parameters, as a function of $\theta,$ in terms of $g,$ $f,$ and $T.$  Differentiating $1=\int p(x\mid\theta)\mathrm{d}x$ with respect to $\theta$ ought to give you some useful information.  I find it helps to work such problems by first assuming $\theta$ is a $1$-vector, so you can focus on the ideas before addressing the complications of multiple parameters (which doesn't change the ideas at all).

Comment: @whuber you appear to be advocating my second suggestion, in which case I know what to do - the answer should be sum(T_i)/n right?

Comment: If u agree with my above comment then I guess my question is why does this wording imply differentiation with respect to theta and not with respect to E(T)?

Comment: It helps to know that the MLE of any one-to-one function of the parameters, $f,$ is just $f$ applied to the MLEs of the parameters.

Comment: Ok, so your f would be E(T(X)) in the question. I think I'm right in saying that even though T is a function of the observations x and not the parameters theta, E(T(X)) will be a function of theta. But could you please explain how this would work for the MLE? I have an expression for E(T(X)) as the derivative of log(g(theta)) but not sure if that helps with your hint? I'm a little confused now sorry